# use doNothing() for method with return type in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, mockito

```
public void attestResults(List<OMInvestigationResultMutableDTO.Id> resultIds, OMRequestSpeciality speciality)
{
  List<Answer.Id> attestIds = new ArrayList<Answer.Id>();
  for (OMInvestigationResultMutableDTO.Id id : resultIds)
  {
    Answer.Id answerId = answerIdFactory.createId(id.getValue(), null);
    attestIds.add(answerId);
  }

  orderManagementServiceProvider.getOrderManagementService()
    .attestResults(attestIds, 
  RequestSpeciality.valueOf(speciality.toString()));
}
```

My problem is how to write unit testing for attestResults()..
I want to try mock orderManagementServiceProvider.getOrderManagementService().attestResults() using doNothing() in mockito.

This is the method orderManagementServiceProvider.getOrderManagementService().attestResults,

```
public List<Id> attestResults(List<Id> answerIds, RequestSpeciality speciality) {
    this.accessHandler.checkAccess(AccessRights.ATTEST_RESULTS);
    ArgumentValidator.argument(answerIds, "AnswerIds").notNull().notEmpty();
    ArgumentValidator.argument(speciality, "Speciality").notNull();
    ResultCreator resultCreator = new ResultCreator(this.resultToolkitAdapter, this.pathologyReportToolkitService);
    return resultCreator.attestResults(answerIds, speciality);
}
```

In this case I have not permission to use powerMockito.

I mocked 
  `when(orderManagementServiceProvider.getOrderManagementService()).thenReturn(omService);`

Comment: Give your entire code- method 2 as well.

Comment: show us the code what you have used for testing

Comment: why would you need powermock, is serviceProvider the class under test or a dependency that is injectable?

Comment: @AbhisekRoy I update my question

Comment: @pvpkiran I edit my question

Comment: How is `orderManagementServiceProvider` set? Constructor? Setter? None of the previous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant line in your *code under test* (cut) is this:

> ```
> orderManagementServiceProvider.getOrderManagementService()
>    .attestResults(attestIds,
>                   RequestSpeciality.valueOf(speciality.toString()));
> ```

Because of the violation of the *Law of Demeter* (Don't talk to strangers!) you have to mock both: the instance of the `OrderManagementService` and of the `OrderManagementServiceProvider`. Then you have to configure the mock of the later to return the mock of the first when `getOrderManagementService()` is called.

However, `doNothing()` only applies to `void` methods on *spy*s (a wrapped concrete instance of the dependency).  `void` methods on *mock*s are not called anyway.

If your method has a return value you have to use `doReturn()` (or `doThrow()`) so that the cut can act on the methods outcome. By default Mockito will return `null`, `0`or `false` respectively.

---

Warning:

The form `when(dependency.someMethodWithReturnValue()).thenReturn()` **does** call the mocked method (and throws away its result). This may lead to NPEs if the method accesses member variables or objects returned by other not configured methods in the mock.

Answer (score -3):

PowerMockito is used only if you want to mock static classes. By looking at this,

```
orderManagementServiceProvider.getOrderManagementService()
.attestResults(attestIds,
```

RequestSpeciality.valueOf(speciality.toString()));

it doesn't look like static class.

```
orderManagementServiceProvider = mock(OrderManagementServiceProvider.class);
doNothing().when(orderManagementServiceProvider).getOrderManagementService.attestResults(any(),any());
```

Comment: In mockito show error when we using doNothing() for method with return values.doNothing() can use for void return method.In powerMockito we can use doNothing() for method with return values